# autowire Spring repository into generic field (Spring 4, Hibernate 4)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, generics, spring-data

I am trying to build extensible application, that uses lot of generics. So far I have code:

```
@Component
@Named
@Scope("session")
@Repository
public interface FrameworkRepository<E extends FrameworkEntity> 
    extends PagingAndSortingRepository<E, Long> {
}

@Component
@Named
@Scope("session")
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends FrameworkRepository<Order> {
}

@Component
@Named 
@Scope("session")
public class FrameworkService<R extends FrameworkRepository> implements Serializable {
    @Autowired
    private R repository;
}

@Component
@Named
@Scope("session")
public class OrderService extends FrameworkService<OrderRepository> {
    public OrderService() { 
    }
}
```

However, when I am trying to use OrderService instance in facelets page, there is exception with the message:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [...FrameworkRepository] 
found for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I guess, that the root problem can be my use of generics. Maybe Spring Data (repositories) can not automaticall create class from the OrderRepository interface, or maybe Spring @Autowired can not find the instance (created by Spring Data on the fly) of OrderRepository and autowire it into generic field.

I know that in any time I can find workarounds without use of generics, but that involves much unnecesary code. Generics can lead to more concise code.

I use Hibernate 4.x, Spring 4.x, JPA 2.1.

Comment: Have you tried autowiring by name, using the `@Qualifier` annotation?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to add `@Named`, `@Component` and `@Repository` together use one of those (and I would suggest `@Repository` in this case) on a single class and in this case it doesn't make sense at all as it is an interface. Your repositories should be singletons and not session scoped they don't keep state so making them session scoped doesn't make sense (only adds complexity). And imho when you have a generic service layer you have the wrong abstraction... A service with a save or update method doesn't make sense it should provide use-cases/services .

Comment: That annotations over your repositories are probably unnecessary, Spring-data should work without tham. `@Scope("session")` is the worst one, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="dk.nmc.imarket.data"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory">
</jpa:repositories>
```

in my applicationContext.xml and I remode unnecesary annotations from the repositories - they are just repositories and not the full Spring beans by name and for session. It helped so far.